# Como guardar variables dentro de un for

Tags: java

He conseguido que en un bucle pregunten los datos de una persona, puede ser de 1 a 3 como max, y al final de preguntar a todas las personas hacer una funcion llamada informe y que diga los datos de cada una de ellas, tal como lo tengo me dice solo una persona, no sé muy como se debería hacer, pongo también los metodos o funciones que estoy usando por si os sirve de ayuda...

```
    Scanner sc=new Scanner (System.in);
    //todo No consigo hacer que una vez pedido 1,2,3 personas me las guarde el informe...
    int i;
    String nombrePersona;
    String apellidoPersona;
    byte edadPersona;
    String nacionalidadPersona;
    boolean gen;
    int numeroPersonas = cuantasPersonas();
    for ( i = 0; i < numeroPersonas; i++) {                    
        System.out.println("Voy a pedir datos de una persona (pedir nombre, nacionalidad)");
        nombrePersona = pideNombre ("Dime tu nombre");
        apellidoPersona= pideNombre ("Dime tu 1º apellido");
        System.out.println("Dime tu edad");
        edadPersona = pideedad ();
        nacionalidadPersona=pideNombre ("Dime tu nacionalidad");
        gen =generos ("Eres Hombre/Mujer");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

public static String informe(String nombre, String apellido, byte edad, String nacionalidad,boolean genero) {
    return nombre +" "+ apellido +", de "+ edad + " años , y nacionalidad " + nacionalidad + " Su género es" + genero;
}

public static boolean generos (String pregunta){
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String gen;
    do {
        System.out.println(pregunta);
        gen=scan.nextLine();
    }while (!gen.equals("Hombre")&&!gen.equals("Mujer"));

    if(gen.equals("Hombre")){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

public static String pideNombre(String mensaje) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(mensaje);
    return scan.nextLine();
}
/**
* Sirve para pedir el total de personas que vamos a pedir los datos
* @param personas Cantidad de personas que vamos a pedir los datos
* @return el numero de personas que vamos a pedir los datos
*/

public static int cuantasPersonas ( ){
    Scanner scan=new Scanner (System.in);
    int personas;
    do{
        System.out.println("Cuantas personas quieres pedir los datos, debe de ser entre 1 y 3");
        personas=Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
    } while (personas>=4||personas<1);
    return personas;

    public static Byte pideedad() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        return Byte.parseByte(scan.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Comment: Supongo que todo eso va en la clase Persona, ¿no?

Comment: Necesitas una lista -o colección- de personas ó un arreglo de personas.

Comment: Lias mucho el codigo. Crea una clase personas donde tengas los metodos y a esos metodo le pasas como parametros las variables que quieras. olvidate de Array es mas engorroso una List

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no deseas crear una clase Persona solo necesitas hacerle unas pequeñas modificaciones al código. Lo que sucede es que estas utilizando las mismas variables para guardar los datos de cada una de las personas lo que hace que los valores se sobrescriban, para solventar este problema puedes hacer uso de arreglos:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static String informe(String nombre, String apellido, byte edad, String nacionalidad, boolean genero) {
        return nombre + " " + apellido + ", de " + edad + " años , y nacionalidad " + nacionalidad + " Su género es" + genero;
    }

    public static boolean generos(String pregunta) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String gen;
        do {
            System.out.println(pregunta);
            gen = scan.nextLine();
        } while (!gen.equals("Hombre") && !gen.equals("Mujer"));
        return gen.equals("Hombre");
    }

    public static String pideNombre(String mensaje) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(mensaje);
        return scan.nextLine();
    }

    /**
     * Sirve para pedir el total de personas que vamos a pedir los datos
     *
     * @param personas Cantidad de personas que vamos a pedir los datos
     * @return el numero de personas que vamos a pedir los datos
     */
    public static int cuantasPersonas() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int personas;
        do {
            System.out.println("Cuantas personas quieres pedir los datos, debe de ser entre 1 y 3");
            personas = scan.nextInt();
        } while (personas >= 4 || personas < 1);
        return personas;

    }

    public static Byte pideEdad() {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        return scan.nextByte();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numeroPersonas = cuantasPersonas();
        String[] nombrePersona = new String[numeroPersonas];
        String[] apellidoPersona = new String[numeroPersonas];
        byte[] edadPersona = new byte[numeroPersonas];
        String[] nacionalidadPersona = new String[numeroPersonas];
        boolean[] gen = new boolean[numeroPersonas];
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroPersonas; i++) {
            System.out.println("Voy a pedir datos de una persona (pedir nombre, nacionalidad)");
            nombrePersona[i] = pideNombre("Dime tu nombre");
            apellidoPersona[i] = pideNombre("Dime tu 1º apellido");
            System.out.println("Dime tu edad");
            edadPersona[i] = pideEdad();
            nacionalidadPersona[i] = pideNombre("Dime tu nacionalidad");
            gen[i] = generos("Eres Hombre/Mujer");
        }

        System.out.println("");

        // Mostrando los datos
        for (int i = 0; i < numeroPersonas; i++) {
            System.out.println("Persona #" + (i + 1));
            System.out.println("Nombre: " + nombrePersona[i]);
            System.out.println("Apellido: " + apellidoPersona[i]);
            System.out.println("Edad: " + edadPersona[i]);
            System.out.println("Nacionalidad: " + nacionalidadPersona[i]);
            System.out.println("Genero: " + (gen[i] ? "Hombre": "Mujer"));

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

}
```

Otra forma mucho mas sencilla sería crear una clase persona con todos esos datos y guardar cada objeto en una lista o arreglo.